# Best approach to develop a mobile version of existing browser mmo game?

Tags: mmo, mobile, browser

our team has developed a MMO browser game (HTML5, Javascript & PHP). The game is similar to Empire GG, Clash of Kings, Game of War etc.

We want to develop a mobile version and the question is which would be the most efficient way/ process we can take advantage of?

Comment: You could try using something like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to port your game (may or may not work well). If that isn't good enough you might have to redevelop from scratch as Philipp suggests in his answer.

Comment: @UnholySheep Those aren't tools where you press a button and your existing web application turns into a smartphone app. They are frameworks which allows you to build applications and then allows you to export that application to different platforms. But in order for that to work you need to develop your app within that framework from the start.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty version is to have an app consisting of nothing but a web view control which loads the web version of your game.

The user experience with this solution might not be ideal, though. It won't be much different from running your game in the mobile browser. How well that works depends on how well your game copes with smaller screen size and touchscreen input instead of mouse input and if you thought about checking for compatibility with mobile browsers when you wrote your HTML and JavaScript.

So you might get better results with a native client. But porting it to a native client means that you need to redevelop your HTML5+Javascript part from scratch. A simple one-to-one port is unlikely to lead to a good player experience. Smartphones simply have a different user experience than desktop PCs. The screen is smaller and touch-input is far less precise than mouse-input. But to make up for that they offer alternative input methods like rotation or pressure sensitivity which aren't available in a browser. That means that you need to come up with different user interface solutions. If you decide to go this route, then there are several technologies available. We don't know your game or your team, so we can not tell you which tool is the best for you.

What you can and should keep is your PHP backend and most of your assets (if they look well on the small screen).